# How to Archive Data from EmployeeDB to ArchiveEmployeeDB by Using BULK Insert and need to insert 1000 records at single time?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
create table #QueueVariable (ID INT)
DECLARE @currentDate as datetimeoffset(7)
SET @currentDate = SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()
INSERT INTO #QueueVariable SELECT ID From [EmployyeDB].[dbo].[EmployeeTable] where CreateDate <DATEADD(m, -6, @currentDate)
        
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [EmployeeArchive].[dbo].[EmaployeeTable] ON
Insert into [EmployeeArchive].[dbo].[EmaployeeTable]([ID] ,[CreateDate],[CreateLogin] ,[CreateUser],[UpdateDate] ,[UpdateLogin] ,[UpdateUser] )
Select * From [EmployyeDB].[dbo].[EmployeeTable] where ID in (SELECT ID from #QueueVariable) and ID not in (select ID from [EmployeeArchive].[dbo].[EmployeeTable])
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [EmployeeArchive].[dbo].[EmaployeeTable] OFF
```

We are using **Insert to into statement** previously, but due to a large amount of data, there is a performance issue now. Looking for BULK Insert or any other better options to archive data.

Answer (score 0):

A more performant option would be to rely on the id column order. You can usually rely on the fact that autoincrement IDs keep increasing. Unfortunately is also not following best practices (we are relying on an id here) and more error prone in case of manual admin interventions.

So, it would be something like this:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [EmployeeArchive].[dbo].[EmployeeTable] ON
INSERT INTO [EmployeeArchive].[dbo].[EmployeeTable] (column1, column2, column3, ...)
SELECT column1, column2, column3, ...
FROM [EmployyeDB].[dbo].[EmployeeTable]
WHERE [EmployyeDB].[dbo].[EmployeeTable].id > max([EmployeeArchive].[dbo].[EmployeeTable].id)
and [EmployyeDB].[dbo].[EmployeeTable].id < (select min([EmployyeDB].[dbo].[EmployeeTable].id where [EmployyeDB].[dbo].[EmployeeTable].CreateDate > DATEADD(month, -2, GETDATE())
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [EmployeeArchive].[dbo].[EmployeeTable] OFF
```

Another option would be to check if there is already an index on createdate, which might help with your original solution.